# MYSQL Query - When col1 has only 'Special' use that else use one of the other

Tags: mysql, sql, having

Following dataset

```
  ID  | Description |   Type
-------------------------------
12204 |     ABC     | Special
12204 |     DEF     | Connector
12541 |     GHI     | Special
12541 |     JKL     | Special
12541 |     MNO     | Hybrid
13292 |     PQR     | Resistor
13292 |     STU     | Connector
13292 |     VWX     | Hybrid
14011 |     YZa     | Special
14012 |     bcd     | Resistor
```

What I want from it is the following:

```
  ID  | Description |   Type
-------------------------------
12204 |     DEF     | Connector
12541 |     MNO     | Hybrid
13292 |     PQR     | Resistor or Connector or Hybrid <-- doesn't matter
14011 |     YZa     | Special
14012 |     bcd     | Resistor
```

So, all I need is the whole dataset according to the Type. If there is only "Special" as Type possible, then I need to use it, but if not then I want to use the one of the others.

I figured out to group everything but then it uses the first row which mostly contains Special...

My Query so far:

```
SELECT ID, Description, Type FROM anyDatabase GROUP BY ID HAVING count(Type) > 1
```

Hope anyone can help :)
Adi

Comment: The last two items will not be fetched when using `count(Type) > 1`

Comment: @KT_Adi don't you think you should accept answer if it fulfills your requirements

Answer (score 3):

You can try it like this

```
SELECT
  l.id,
  l.description,
  IF(r.type IS NULL, l.type, r.type) AS `Type`
FROM newtable as l
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
         FROM newtable
         WHERE type <> 'Special') as r
    on r.id = l.id
GROUP BY l.id
```

### SQL Fiddle Demo

Comment: Actually I clicked on the 'Vote Up'-Button but it raises up to 4 and switches back to 3, if thats what you mean =/

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution:

```
SELECT 
    newtable.id, 
    newtable.description, 
    newtable.type
FROM newtable 
INNER JOIN(
           SELECT
              id, 
              MAX(CASE WHEN Type!='Special' THEN Type END) type
           FROM newtable
           GROUP BY id
      ) mx
  ON newtable.id=mx.id
     AND newtable.type=COALESCE(mx.type, 'Special')
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4e0b/5) (thanks to raheel shan for the fiddle!)